# Python to C# conversion

Tags: c#, python

In python i'm creating `.an` file using

```
commandStr="dpan.exe -np -Lwork_%s.lib -Owork_%s.lib %s %s.an" %( option1, option2, Sourcefile, Destination file)
os.system( commandStr )
```

This will create the `.an` file (Destination file) from Sourcefile.

Now i'm converting this line of code from Python to C#
So how do i do this in C#. How to run the `commandStr` in C#
Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) method:

```
Process.Start(
    "dpan.exe", 
    string.Format(
        "-np -Lwork_{0}.lib -Owork_{1}.lib \"{2}\" \"{3}.an\"", 
        option1, option2, sourceFile, destinationFile
    )
);
```

Comment: its throwing an error like `The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Try specifying the full path to `dpan.exe` or put the executable in the PATH or the working directory.

Comment: are you sure you have dpan.exe available for your .net app?

Comment: @ Rafal Ziolkowski . Yes ... it is

Comment: As you can see the process name and the command line arguments are two separate arguments of the Process.Start method so the space is automatically added.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of `os.system` is [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) in C#.